# When width of an element is greater than the width of a viewport…

Tags: html, css, xhtml

We use overflow property to specify whether scroll bars should be provided when content overflows element’s box.

Is there a similar property with which we could specify whether horizontal scroll bars should be provided when the width of an element is greater than the width of a viewport ( ie display area )?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have to be done with JavaScript.  You would most likely want to write a function that would re-size the element to have the same width as the viewport and set `scroll:auto` on that element to mimic the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the overflow-x css property.

Comment: Overflow-x is usefull when content overflows elements width - that is not the case here

Comment: And you can't set your element width to 100% or whatever percentage applies to your situation?